# Windows no longer available in boot menu after installing elementary OS Freya

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I installed elementary OS Freya from a LiveUSB (I didn't have to disable anything in the bios, I just pressed F12 and chose the USB option) after shrinking my Windows partition by 100GB. I allocated 12GB (2x my RAM) for the swap space and the rest for "/" (root).

I was following this [guide](http://www.tweaking4all.com/os-tips-and-tricks/uefi-dual-boot-windows81-ubuntu/) up until it tells you to reboot into Windows:

> Reboot your computer … and most likely your computer will boot straight into Windows …

However, my laptop boots straight into elementary OS. Any idea how to get Windows back as a boot option?

Cheers

Additional information:
Alienware M14xR2, with Windows 7

[Output from Boot Repair] (1)

[GParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCjDh.png)

edit: I have [these options] (2) available in "Advanced" option in Boot Repair. I can change the "OS to boot by default". However, that does nothing. [Shows "Windows 7 loader" as an option] (3) but selecting it simply restarts the computer.

Output of *parted -l*:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16           diag
 2      41.9MB  21.2GB  21.2GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 3      21.2GB  645GB   624GB   primary   ntfs
 4      645GB   750GB   105GB   extended
 5      645GB   738GB   92.9GB  logical   ext4
 6      738GB   750GB   12.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Can't post more than 2 links. So posting them here.
[Link (1)](http://paste2.org/WaYy4zfm)
[Link (2)](http://i.imgur.com/Wm8uvcW.png)
[Link (3)](https://i.imgur.com/9RJN5pv.jpg)

Comment: The link to guide already states that you will be able to destroy your pc, i do hope you followed the review attentively and **did** create a recovery disk

Comment: What do you mean "destroy your PC"? I'm very well aware that things could go wrong if that's what you mean. Does that mean I shouldn't ask for assistance when something does break?

Comment: Did you allocate swap space on you Windows partition? If so, it's likely that Windows partition is reformatted.

Comment: Would you mind to open Terminal on elementary OS, run `sudo parted -l` (it will ask for your password, that's fine!) and add the output to your question?

Comment: @DuongPham I allocated the swap space on the free space (what I shrunk from the Windows partition). My Windows installation and files are on /dev/sda3 see [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZDNRI7X.png)

Comment: @embik please see edit :)

Comment: You do not have UEFI (you use msdos partition table). Why did you follow a guide for UEFI when you could install normally

Answer (score 1):

I think your windows partition is `/dev/sda3`.
`/dev/sda2` seems to be the dell recovery partition, so can you just try editing grub entry by hitting `e` on the windows grub entry and change sda2 to sda3, `F10` afterwards and post back please. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)I edited it [like so](http://i.imgur.com/dVyRfpl.jpg) and then pressed F10. Same thing happens though, I get a ["Windows is loading files..."](http://i26.tinypic.com/mucxy.png) progress bar but the laptop restarts once that finishes and I'm back at the same screen again.